# Running Python 3 from Light Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, lighttable

I am trying Light Table and learning how to use it. Overall, I like it, but I noticed that the only means of making the watches and inline evaluation work in Python programs uses Python 2.7.8, making it incompatible with some of my code. Is there a way to make it use Python 3 instead?

I looked on Google and GitHub and I couldn't find anything promising.

I am using a Mac with OS X 10.10.2. I have an installation of Python 3.4.0 that runs fine from the Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with using a syntax that was only valid on Python3.3.
- Go to Settings:User Behaviour
- add the line (find the real path of your python binary):
      [:app :lt.plugins.python/python-exe "/usr/bin/python3.4"]
- Save and test in your lighttable

It worked for me :) 
Hope it helps

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Here is the line I added, for everyone's reference:
`[:app :lt.plugins.python/python-exe "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4"]`

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Ctrl + Space` to bring up the control pane. Then start typing `Set Syntax` and select `Set Syntax to Python`. Start typing your Python then press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to build and run the program.

Comment: I hit `Ctrl + Space`. I typed `Python` in the search box in the sidebar that showed on the right side and there were no results.

Comment: Then start typing `Set Syntax`

Comment: I hit `Ctrl + Space` and typed `Set Syntax`. The one match that came up said "Editor: Set current editor syntax". I clicked on that and it gave me a bunch of choices. The only one that looked relevant was "Python". I picked that and nothing seemed to happen. I typed `import sys; sys.version` into the editor and tried evaluating the `sys.version`. It came back as `2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`, just like it did before.

Comment: So that means you haven't added Python 3 to your system path.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If I type `echo $PATH` in the Terminal, I see a bunch of directories including `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin`. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Perhaps, Light Table doesn't support Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It worked for me after saving the file with a .py extension and then typing Cmd+Enter.

Comment: I typed `import sys; sys.version`, saved it in a file with a .py extension, selected the `sys.version`, pressed `Cmd + Enter`, and it showed `2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`.

Comment: It worked only because it use the 2.7 python. Cannot use Python 3 without solving the Unicode issue see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> `Settings:User Behaviour`

```
 [:app :lt.plugins.python/python-exe "/path_to_your_custom_bin/bin/python3.4"]
```

There is an issue with `Unicode` ( 'unicode' is not defined), and I also needed to modify `ltmain.py` to work with Python3 see here:

https://github.com/eduardflorinescu/lighttable_python3_patch/blob/master/ltmain.py

Make sure you backup the orginal `ltmain.py`, you can diff the two to see what are the differences and what was changed: